# C# ODBC Query is very slowly

Tags: c#, odbc

My access database had 700 records,every record had 50 fields。I use ODBC Query of PHP which query speed is very fast,but i use ODBC Query of C# ,it speed is very slowly,codes below:

```
m_conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=real");//This DSN set by through the windows control panel,ODBC manager,system dsn 
m_conn.Open();
string sqlstr="select  * from table1 where id = 1";
OdbcCommand selectCMD = new OdbcCommand(sqlstr, m_conn);
OdbcDataReader myreader;
myreader = selectCMD.ExecuteReader();
if (myreader == null)
   return null;
string s =myreader["field"].ToString();//here,execution speed is very slow,why?
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Don't select more data for your application than you need to process.

Your statement `select * from table1 where id = 1` is selecting all fields.  If you only need the field named `field`, than change your select statement to `select field from table1 where id = 1`.

If you provide additional information on your database structure I may be able to be of more help.

Comment: My database structure below:
<pre>48 float fields,
1 char 64 fields,
1 id of AUTO_INCREMENT   field.</pre>
I need this all fields,but I test the same query statement on ODBC-Query of php ,Its speed is very fast.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of suggestions here. I am guessing that you are accessing this code multiple times, which is where the slowness is coming in. This is most likely caused by you not disposing/closing of the connections properly. Below is the code refactored with the using clause, which enforces the use of Dispose after the call.

Also, instead of using the asterisk, specifying the name of the columns will help access optimize the query.

Finally, if you are only concerned about 1 variable, consider changing the query to only return the one value you are looking for and changing the call to an `ExecuteScalar()` call.

```
// Consider specifying the fields you are concerned with
string sqlstr="select * from table1 where id = 1";

using (var m_conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=real"))//This DSN set by through the  windows control panel,ODBC manager,system dsn 
using (var selectCMD = new OdbcCommand(sqlstr, m_conn))
{
    m_conn.Open();

    using (var myreader= selectCMD.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (myreader == null)
            return null;
        string s =myreader["field"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your responding.The code of above is simplified by me,I use single step breakpoint debug,Stuck in this statement about ten seconds:<h1>string s =myreader["field"].ToString();</h1>,this  speed slow beyond imagination.Is it because of my system?My system is win7 64 bit;

Comment: Have you tried using the code above? Especially try changing the select statement to "Select field from table1" Access is not a very fast db to begin with and specifying the field will definitely help the db.

Comment: Yes,I tried. select statement : "Select field from table1" is very fast.I used MFC of VS2010 tried.It is also very slow.Therefore, I think this is the windows system ODBC driver problem .Thank everyone.